# convert byte[] array from MySQL into hex with dashes in java?

Tags: java, mysql, hex, arrays

I am looking for a JavaUtil class if already available to convert the byte[] array into **hexString with dashes**. I looked around couldn't find one for this type of problem.

Here is my scenario:

Byte[] array is stored in MySQL as explained [here](http://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/).

so when I run

```
select HEX(id) as hexi, (
 insert(
   insert(
     insert(
       insert(
         hex(
           concat(substr(id,5,4),substr(id,3,2),
                  substr(id,1,2),substr(id,9,8))
         ),
         9,0,'-'),
     14,0,'-'),
   19,0,'-'),
 24,0,'-')
) as hex_dashes from my_table;
```

I get

```
hexi                                              hex_dashes
22E179345A5C11E69A64F9BBBC7C3AAC  5A5C11E6-7934-22E1-9A64-F9BBBC7C3AAC
```

you can quickly notice that hex_dashes is rearranged version of hexi string (look for 22E1 after 2nd dash in hex_dashes is the start string of hexi. how this rearrangement is done is explained in the article linked above).

In the above query, id type is `byte[]`.

Now, I want a java Util function to return hex_dashes string given byte[] array.

I have this method which returns hexi but not hex_string.

```
static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    public static String byteArrayToHexString( byte [] raw ) {
        if ( raw == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder( 2 * raw.length );
        for ( final byte b : raw ) {
            hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
                    .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }
```

I am wondering if there is any way I could get hex with dashes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following util-method:

```
static String hexDashes(byte[] raw) {
        final String hex = byteArrayToHexString(raw);
        return String.format("%s-%s-%s-%s-%s", hex.substring(8, 16), hex.substring(4, 8), hex.substring(0, 4), hex.substring(16, 20), hex.substring(20, 32));
}
```

It takes the raw `byte[]`, converts it to the hexi, and just inserts the according substrings from the computed string between the dashes. If you already computed the hex-String for prior usage, it would be faster to just use that as parameter `hex`. You could also use string concatination instead of `String.format(...)`.